# Converter DATE no SQL (Oracle) de UTC para o fuso-horário brasileiro

Tags: sql, oracle

Tenho a seguinte query:

```
SELECT c.name, t.sequential_id AS sequencialid, 
       CONCAT(SUBSTR (REPLACE (m.content, '¿', ''), 0, 30), '...') AS content, 
       m.direction, 
       (CASE WHEN TRUNC("M"."DATE") = TRUNC(SYSDATE) THEN TO_CHAR
        ("M"."DATE", 'HH24:MI') ELSE TO_CHAR(TRUNC("M"."DATE")) END) AS"date"
      FROM portal_ticket t,
           portal_contact c,
           (select tm.ticket_id,
                   m.*,
                   RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY tm.ticket_id ORDER BY "M"."DATE" DESC, ID) ordem
              FROM portal_ticket_message tm, portal_message m
             WHERE tm.message_id = m.id) m
    WHERE t.customer_identity = c.identity
       AND t.id = m.ticket_id
       AND m.ordem = 1
    ORDER BY t.sequential_id DESC
```

Tenho o *"M"."DATE"* que é do tipo DATE (apesar da saída ser em CHAR, como pode ser visto na query), porém ele está com dados em UTC e eu gostaria de  converte-los pro nosso fuso horário, como posso fazer?

Estou com dificuldade dada a query já está complicada pra mim (onde eu usei CASE pra, caso o registro seja de hoje, retornar apenas as horas, SE NÃO, retornar apenas a data).

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#i1007699      FROM_TZ

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro padronize os dados, quando for realizar as operações que seja data com data e hora com hora. Separe em coluna, posterior a isso execute os cálculos. Tente criar uma view com as informações no formato que deseja e posterior a utilize seus dados já organizados. Lembrando do formarto dd/MM/yyyy (date)